# Can I apply for a short-term visa while another country's visa is in process?

Tags: long-stay-visas, croatia, schengen-visas, application-status

I have applied to Germany for a long-term national visa under the family reunion category. It has been around 3 months now and I still haven't heard from the visa officer. The entire process is very time consuming and I am not sure when I will hear from the authorities.

Now, I need to travel to a Croatia for a few days. Is it possible to apply for that visa while the German long term visa application is still under consideration?

Comment: Croatia is not a Schengen country.  Go for it.

Answer (score 2):

The [original version of this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/95836/revisions) makes it clear that the question was asked because of the incorrect belief that Croatia is a Schengen country.  It is not.  There is nothing preventing an application for a Croatian visa while a German visa application is pending.

Comment: unless of course he doesn't have his passport because it's at the German consulate or embassy...